Product of Subgroups of an Abelian Group Based on The Kernel of Their Associated Endomorphisms?
In an abelian group $A$, all quotient groups are embedded in $A$, so there is a bijection between the subgroups of $A$ and the endomorphism semigroup of $A$. I'd like to define an operation, $\circ$, on two subgroups of $H,K\leq A$ such that $H\circ K=\ker(\varphi_H\circ\varphi_K)$, where $\varphi_H,\varphi_K:A\to A$ are endomorphisms and $H=\ker\varphi_H$ and $K=\ker\varphi_K$. The semigroup of subgroups of $A$, $(S,\circ)$, would naturally be isomorphic to the semigroup of endomorphisms of $A$. Is there any simple formula for $\circ$, perhaps based on the generators of $H,K$, to calculate $H\circ K$ without finding $\ker(\varphi_H\circ\varphi_K)$ directly?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

That first sentence makes two claims both of which are false. It's not true that all quotients of an abelian group are also subgroups ($\mathbb{Z}$ is a counterexample), and it's not true that there's a bijection between endomorphisms and subgroups ($\mathbb{Z}^2$ is a counterexample), assuming that the map you intend to be a bijection sends an endomorphism to its image. This map is neither injective nor surjective in general, and for $\mathbb{Z}^2$ it is neither.


Link to Diagram 
What you have is a collection of diagrams such as these, where if the bottom square commutes, then there exists a unique morphism $u$ such that the total resulting diagram commutes.    However, notice that in Homological Algebra, you need consistently directed arrows for many proofs.  Therefore, instead of $\phi: A \to A/H$ you could put $\pi$ there for the inverse map.  So what I'm sayin is try building up to  a large grid diagram.  We already know that the sequence(s) (one for each $H,K$ but only $H$ is shown) in the first line(s) of the diagram are short exact sequences (SES).  These are popular in homological algebra theory.
So again instead of $h$ you'd put $\vartheta$.  Of course you're going to turn it into a product rather that coproduct diagram, but the result is isomorphic to the coproduct by axiom of abelian category.
Forgot to mention that each SES in $\textbf{Ab}$ is split-exact I believe. That's how we got the extra morphisms in the other direction.
Aha, it's called the Splitting Lemma

Just realized the maps needed to "split" might not exist for general abelian groups...

I have no idea why this answer has 3 upvotes and no downvotes. Short exact sequences in $\text{Ab}$ do not split in general, and the smallest counterexample is $0 \to C_2 \to C_4 \to C_2 \to 0$.
